# Distributing py program involving PhantomJS

Tags: python, deployment, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have a Python program that works with Selenium and PhantomJS, and I’d like to distribute it. The functionality is quite simple; it goes onto a website, fills certain forms and returns the outcome, without any visible browser action.
The problem is that I can’t expect an arbitrary user to have PhantomJS installed on their computers. How should I approach the distribution process?
I already checked Setuptools and PythonAnywhere, but I don’t think they work for what I want.

Edit: May be too hopeful, but I'd like to be able to distribute it for Windows, OSX and Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh sorry. Hopefully it'll be finished as cross-platform compatible, but for now Windows works too.

Comment: I'd use nw.js plus InnoSetup for this task. Granted it's not Python-specific but you can run anything you want from it and creating GUI is a breeze.

Comment: @Vaviloff thank you for your answer. GUI isn't my concern at all. I checked nw.js and it does seem helpful, but I'd still like to know if I have a chance with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do it is through a web application built on [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) (one of many great python web frameworks) and hosted on PythonAnywhere.

To use PhantomJS and Selenium in PythonAnywhere you have to ask for Docker Consoles. Instructions here: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1320/